# PDO exec returns 0 instead of rows affected

Tags: php, pdo, exec

i got a problem with PDO::exec() method. I'm trying to figure it out for an hour now and still got nowhere. It probably will be some small thing i'm missing.

I use exec to update (and delete in another piece of code) one row in database. According to manual, exec should return number of rows affected. But in my case (both update and delete), exec runs, physicaly updates database, but still returns 0.

Here is my code for the update statement (delete is similar)

```
$data = Array(
    'title' => $entity->getTitle(),
    'subtitle' => $entity->getSubtitle(),
    'text' => $entity->getText(),
);
$response = $this->conn->exec("UPDATE entries SET ? WHERE id = ?", $data, $entity->getId());
if($response <> 1) throw new Exception('Update statement affected '.$response.' rows');
```

Code above will output Uncaught exception: Update statement affected 0 rows, even though the row is actually updated.

Id I comment the line with exception, everything runs fine (but i cannot handle errors).

Is anyone able to help??

PS.: i'm using Nette Framework, so the query with ?'s  is valid.. Contents of $entity are also valid

Comment: is this valid php `$response <> 1`

Comment: @DevZer0 - [Yes, it is](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: In the manual function prototype shows only 1 parameter, `public int PDO::exec ( string $statement )` i don't see anywhere its mentioned you can bind params on the fly with it.

Comment: @DevZer0 the Nette framework overrides `exec()` to implement the prepated statement functionality.

Comment: @MrCode ok thanks. I haven't used Nette. i will add it to my growing list of things to check out :) thanks again.

Comment: As DevZer0 pointed out, nette actually uses execute. It didn't occur to me that it overrides original exec :-(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pdo exec doesn't support prepared statements. So, whatever behavior of `exec()` method has nothing to do with PDO but belongs to whatever framework you are using.

Comment: As DevZer0 said, Nette executes a prepared statement even when using exec. But still, the return value is false (0) where it should be true :-(

Comment: I am having the same problem. Because, the exact statement is working well on other website but showing error in one website. Weird